# How to fetch nested rows in datagrid dynamically at run time in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I am working on WPF application where I need to display table of user's details and also need to show it's details in nested.

Like : there is first table is UserDetails like :

```
UserId | UserName
----------------------
1      | UserABC
```

and another table is UserOrders like :

```
OrderId | UserId | OrderName | OrderPrice
1           1        iPhone     $20
2           1        Card       $5 
3           1        Pen        $2
```

So in C# side I have two models first one is for User's Details and Second one is for User's Orders. And on WPF side I want to display like :

```
UserName:
UserABC
   OrderName | OrderPrice
     iPhone       $20
     Card         $5
     Pen          $2
```

means in nested type. Now I have achieve this result by using help of http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/ in which it load all the users and it's order at a time and then load User's Orders from that list so sometimes it can be happen that user's may have long list of orders so I want to achieve result like when we click on User's Name like UserABC at that time in backend side we get Id of that User and then we fetch that user's order list and display it as a nested list for particular that user.

So please can you guide me that how to achieve it ?

My Code is display below :

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dgUsers" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
       <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="ClientName" Binding="{Binding ClientName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
       </DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <DockPanel Background="GhostWhite">
                 <Grid Margin="0,10">
                      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
             </DockPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
       </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

And on load time

```
public UserDetailsWindow()
{
      InitializeComponent();
      fillClientsList();
}

public void fillClientsList()
{
      var result = _client.ClientList();
      dgUsers.ItemsSource = result;
}
```

I am trying to use `LoadingRowDetails` property in datagrid but when I am trying to fetch parent row details then it's now giving me result. Like

```
var root = e.DetailsElement;
var detail = root.FindName("UserId");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouping data on Datagrid wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42898450/grouping-data-on-datagrid-wpf)

Comment: @Filburt I have already explain in my question that at the load time I don't want to bind nested rows with parent rows. When user will click on parent rows at that time by using parent row's Id nested rows will be fetch from database and will bind with datagrid as a nested rows.